# is this code thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I would like to know if this code is thread-safe and why if it's not the case.

```
    static IMyInterface _myinterface;
        public static IMyInterface someStuff
        {
            get
            {
                if (_myinterface== null)
                {
                    _myinterface= MyServiceLocator.GetCurrent().GetInstance<IMyInterface>();
                }

                return _myinterface;
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to use a lock.

```
private static readonly object m_lock = new object();
private static IMyInterface _myinterface;

public static IMyInterface someStuff
{
    get
    {
        lock(m_lock)
        {
           if (_myinterface == null)
           {
             //create instance
           }

           return _myinterface;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code... doesn't make sense that an uncompilable response is accepted as the answer to anyone else.

Comment: @Dargos @lan: LOL sorry I didn't notice `someStuff` is a static property. Thanks for prompting/editing.

Comment: @Danny I would be hesitant to recommend double-checked locking as it is so easy to get wrong. It does work in this instance, agreed, but it can be very problematic. I would only really recommend it if performance was extremely important. BTW In theory `_myinterface` should be volatile, but in practice this will not cause any bad side effects in this example. Also `m_lock` should be readonly.

Comment: @chibacity: Sorry but can you provide a link or something? I didn't quite understand.

Comment: @chibacity: Why it can be very problematic? Why `_myinterface` has to be volatile? And why `m_lock` has to be readonly?

Comment: @Danny See [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), chapter "Third version - attempted thread-safety using double-check locking".

Comment: @chibacity @Christian.K: Thanks for the nice link. But my question remains: why `_myinterface` should be vilatile and why `m_lock` should be readonly? I don't think they have to be.

Comment: @Danny Firstly, a common fault with double-checked locking is that a series of steps are taken to initialize the object i.e. multiple statements. In this case a caller will see the object is not null and try to use when it is semi-initialized. I have seen this enough times for this to be perhaps be considered as an anti-pattern. I fixed one a couple of days ago, the pattern was totally unnecessary from a performance standpoint, but had introduced a serious MT bug.

Comment: @Danny Secondly, `_myinterface` in theory should be `volatile` as different threads may have cached values for it so may not see the updated value. This is all related to CPU cache and register optimizations. Thread1 may update its cached copy, and thread2 will not see this. In practice though, thread2 will see the update when it enters the lock as in effect memory will be synchronized. There are no bad side-effects in this example, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: @Danny Thirdly, `m_lock` should be `readonly` as someone can come along and re-initialize `m_lock` to point at a new object. Locking depends on threads seeing the same locking object.

Comment: @chibacity: I agree with your first opinion, double-checking is not so easy to use as `Lazy<T>` or nested singleton. For the second one, I don't think different thread may have cached values for `_myinterface`, because it's implemented as a singleton and it's readonly. And for the third, if some one can come along and re-initialize `m_lock`, he also can delete your `readonly` keyword, because he has access to the source code. You can't prevent a guy who has access to source code from destroying. It's better to make it `readonly`, but not necessary.

Comment: @Danny Threads may have cached values for `_myinterface` as this is an issue related to hardware not software. There are many layers of caching in CPUs, ultimately leading back to CPU registers. This optimization happens at the hardware level, the thread knows nothing of it. Unfortunately this can lead to threads seeing different versions of data as they are accessing independent caches. This is one area where the virtual machine concept breaks down, as this problem is directly related to how the hardware works.

Comment: @Danny Just because someone could come along and delete the `readonly` keyword from the source code for the lock object, is not a good reason for not using it. For best practice lock objects should be marked as `readonly`.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, it is not. However, there are quite some options to make it thread safe appart from plain locking or the double checked pattern - which is not guaranteed to work on all (possible) implementations of the CLR.

Also note that unless you expect high contention, double checked locking is really not required and will hardly make a difference. It is relatively easy to get wrong (see the other (initially) wrong implementation in one of the answers as a great example).

See [Jon Skeet's article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on the subject for more information.

Comment: +1 For pointing out that double-checked locking is problematic. Fixed a classic example of this just the other day.

Comment: A code example of a safe way of doing this would add to your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's not.
Because between the only way to be sure is to add a lock on it. It could possibly have two threads into the if statement !

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't, you want to do something more like this. Notice the double check on the `_myinterface==null`. This is because after your first check, another thread may already be in the lock creating it. So you need to double check as soon as you reach your lock.

```
static IMyInterface _myinterface;
private static object lockObj = new object();
public static IMyInterface someStuff
{
   get
   {
      if (_myinterface== null)
      {
         lock(lockObj)
         {
            if (_myinterface== null)
            {             
                _myinterface= MyServiceLocator.GetCurrent().GetInstance<IMyInterface>();
            }
         }
      }
      return _myinterface;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't because there can be multiple initialization threads that would try to access the singleton at the same time.

This could work:

```
    static object _lock=new object(); 
    static IMyInterface _myinterface;
    public static IMyInterface someStuff
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock) {
                if (_myinterface== null)
                {
                    _myinterface= MyServiceLocator.GetCurrent().GetInstance<IMyInterface>();
                }
            }
            return _myinterface;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

Why?

Two calls come into `someStuff` one gets past `if(_myInterface null)` but is interrupted `_myInterface = MYServiceLoc...`. The second thread get's all the way in and completes before going to sleep. The second wakes up, assigns to _myInterface.

Both end up calling MyServiceLocator...GetInstance(), both assign to _myInterface, and both can return different values for _myInterface.

Answer (score 0):

No, could happen that two different threads instantiate different instances and owerwrites previous saved value of the _`myInterface`.

Just imagine that Thread#1 entered `if` block

```
if (_myinterface== null)                 
{
 // ... here
```

and Thread#2 also reading _`myinterface` and entering this block too, in this time Thread#1 instantiated object and updated reference of `_myinterface`. 
But in the same time Thread#2 already cached value of `_myinterface` (it is NULL) and creating new one object and owerwriting value which was stored by Thread#1.

Wrap getter by lock() so only one thread can enter in (see an other answer regarding double lock)